# Why does 善悪{ぜんあく}の彼岸{ひがん} mean "Beyond Good and Evil"? In particular, how does 彼岸 correspond to "beyond"?

Tags: word-choice, words, religion

Episode 9 of Parasyte is titled 善悪{ぜんあく}の彼岸{ひがん}, translated as "Beyond Good and Evil". It's also apparently the official Japanese name for the "Beyond Good and Evil" book that was originally written by famous philosopher Nietzsche.

善悪{ぜんあく} is straightforward and I've known it before. But apparently 彼岸{ひがん} is a [common word according to jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BD%BC%E5%B2%B8) that refers to a common Buddhist holiday in Japan. My question is, how in the heck does that word imply "beyond"?

My only guess is that jisho.org says that 彼岸 can mean "nirvana". I would guess that this "nirvana" is in the sense of being liberated from something mundane (e.g. being liberated/freed from the concept of simple good and evil). Is this the correct idea??

Comment: Did you check a monolingual dictionary? There is also the literal meaning, 向こう側の岸 (the shore on the other side).

Comment: @Leebo I wish there were a way to easily suggest updates to jisho.org (or other dictionaries) when they're missing relevant definitions like this <.<. Anyways, Thanks! <3

Comment: Under "Links" on the left side, there is "Edit in JMdict". Unless you were suggesting something easier.

Comment: @Leebo I remember the last time I tried to do something on jisho, it was a ton of trouble and ultimately didn't work ;-;. I'll try the edit in JMDict though... Hopefully it works @.@.

Comment: BTW [jensetis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jenseits) (as used in the Nitzsche's work) is literally 'that side'.

Comment: Update: we got jisho to update the definition. Huzzah! ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the Buddhistic connotation<sup>1</sup> could be intended, it can be understood as a literal usage of [彼岸](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BD%BC%E5%B2%B8/#jn-183575):

> ４ 向こうがわの岸。

It simply means the other side, usually over a river<sup>2</sup>, whence *beyond*. The antonym is [此岸{しがん}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%AD%A4%E5%B2%B8/#jn-94615).

---

<sup>1</sup>[彼岸](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%BC%E5%B2%B8) (bold added)

> サンスクリットのpāram（パーラム）の意訳であり、仏教用語としては、「波羅蜜」（Pāramitā パーラミター）の意訳「至彼岸」に由来する[3](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%BC%E5%B2%B8)。
>
> Pāramitāをpāram（彼岸に）+ita（到った）、つまり、「彼岸」という場所に至ることと解釈している。**悟りに至るために越えるべき渇愛や煩悩を川（暴流）に例え、その向こう岸**に涅槃があるとする（三途川とは無関係）。

<sup>2</sup> I guess it could be a strait. So Dover and Calais are 彼岸 to each other. Not that they are called as such normally, but they can be.

Comment: I would suggest there is still a strong Buddhist sense here.  To speak of the "other shore" in Buddhist sutras and texts is not only a way to refer to nirvana but also to refer what is "beyond life and death" (some would say those two are the same, not a debate I'm trying to start here).  In this sense, "beyond good and evil" makes very good sense as an interpretation for this phrase.